# RTRIM with 2 arguments

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Good day,

Can u give me advice, 
how can i replace

```
RTRIM(path,'?')
```

with using regexp_replace or another functions, which is possible to use in hive?

thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to trim everything after `?`?

Comment: @SalmanA I need to trim `?` from the end of the line(`path`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **[regexp_extract](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)** function.

**Example:**

im trying to extract all characters of string except for last `?` using regexp_extract fucntion.

```
hive> select regexp_extract(string("?hi?"),"(.*)\\?",1);
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| ?hi  |
+------+--+
```